# Getting inappropriate output converting object to string

Tags: javascript, c#, string, object

I want to extract data from object but getting inappropriate output.

I am passing Id that is **11** from ajax post in the form of `json.stringify`.

```
[WebMethod]
public static int GetData(object ID)
{
    string a = ID.ToString(); // Getting:`System.Object[]` instead of my id `11`
}

console.log(Params)//FILE_ID[0]=11
 console.log(Params['FILE_ID']);//11
 $.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify({ FileID: Params['FILE_ID'] }),
 });
```

How to get just **id from object**?

Comment: Show your `JavaScript` code, you are probably passing an array.

Comment: If you are passing an ID from javascript, then why did you use a parameter with object type?? Anyway for further details please can you include your javascript code?

Comment: @ArghyaC:See my updated question

Comment: @SuvethanNantha:See my updated question

Comment: Why cant you have string as parameter type (instead of object) in GetData?

Comment: @AnkitVijay:when i am taking string as an parameter type it is not working.only object is working

Comment: I think the clue is System.Object[], have you tried, to cast it to array first and then convert it to string

Answer (score 1):

Instead of below code

```
string a = ID.ToString(); // Getting:`System.Object[]` instead of my id `11`
```

use this code and see whether you can get the ID

```
string a = ID["FileID"];
```

or

```
string a = ID["FileID"].ToString();
```

Hope this helps you.